# list of abbreviations without displaying the page

Tags: nomencl

In fact, I want to set a list of abbreviations, but when the abbreviations are displayed they include the number of the page which is not the right page and I don't want the number page to appear in the list of abbreviations, here is the code that I used:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage[a4paper,right=20mm,left=25mm,top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}


\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\makeatother
\title {thesis title}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Liste des abréviations}
\printnomenclature
\chapter*{Introduction générale}
Blablablablablablablablablablablablablablalabla\\blablablablablablablabla 

Modern World (MW) \nomenclature{MW}{: Modern World}
\doublespacing
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `refpage` option of `nomencl` if the page number should not appear in the list of abbreviations.

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage[a4paper,right=20mm,left=25mm,top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}


\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\makeatother
\title {thesis title}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Liste des abréviations}
\printnomenclature
\chapter*{Introduction générale}
Blablablablablablablablablablablablablablalabla\\blablablablablablablabla 

Modern World (MW) \nomenclature{MW}{: Modern World}
\doublespacing
\end{document}
```